# Readline: read three input line-by-line then loop if true

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am forming an input that has this structure:

```
var nodeArray = [
  {
    position: null,
    value: null
  },
  {
    position: null,
    value: null
  },
  // ...
]
```

User Input is read line-by-line. Each line in the list below is `prompt` argument in `rl.setPrompt(prompt)` for a single iteration,

1. Insert position at which you want to insert this node>
2. Insert value of this node>
3. Would you like to insert another node>

   - if `Yes`, loop...*start again at step 1*
   - if `No`, resolve `promise` and close `rl`.

With my understanding of node.js, I was able to write code for a simple structure like this:

```
var array = [
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
  //...
]
```

The code for user input to form `array`:

**input.js**

```
'use strict';                                                         

const readline = require('readline');                                 

const rl = readline.createInterface({                                 
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout                                              
});                                                                   

module.exports = {
  init : async function(arr) {                                        
    this.arr = arr;
    const pr = await this.userInputOn();                              
    return pr;                                                        
  },                                                                  

  promptUpdater : function() {
    rl.setPrompt(`Insert ${this.arr.length}th array Element> `);      
    rl.prompt();                                                      
  },                                                                  

  userInputOn : function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {                        
      this.promptUpdater();
      rl.on('line', (line) => {
        if(line === "close") resolve(this.arr);                       
        else {
          this.arr.push(+line);                                       
          this.promptUpdater();                                       
        }                                                             
      });                                                             
    });                                                               
  },                                                                  
}
```

Code that uses *input.js* code:

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

const stdIn = require('input');

const input = stdIn.init([]);

input.then(function fulfilled(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

I am unable to extend `input.js` code to suit my requirement to form `nodeArray` structure. Also, this code has some glitch like, it never closes `rl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing asynchronous code, you should always try to wrap the smallest possible task into a Promise. In this case, that would be: Prompt for a question, wait for the answer. As we only want to listen to one answer, we just use `.once` instead of `.on`:

```
  function prompt(question) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    rl.setPrompt(question);
    rl.prompt();
    rl.once("line", resolve);
   });
 }
```

Now that we have that, creating a node is simple:

```
  async function createNode() {
   return {
    position: await prompt("Position?"),
    value: await prompt("Value?"),
  };
 }
```

Looping is also straight forward (if we use async / await) and does not require any recursion:

```
 async function createNodes() {
   const result = [];
   while(true) {
     result.push(await createNode());
     if(await prompt("Continue? Yes / No") === "No")
       break;
   }
   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Please give reference of some reading materials from where I can learn good practices like -- *When writing asynchronous code, you should always try to wrap the smallest possible task into a Promise*

Comment: @haslo that is my personal advice :)